# Is it possible to charge one discharged smartphone from other?

Tags: battery

Suppose u are having 2 twin smartphones of same brand. one is fully charged and other one is fully discharged.

My question is that Is it possible to charge one discharged smartphone from fully charged other smartphone?

Comment: If the smartphones has OTG support, then you can connect them using OTG cable and USB cable. I tried this on two different phones. One was charging from the other. Didn't try to know why the other wasn't the first to charge.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759365/connect-two-android-phones-with-usb-cable

Comment: The fact optical USB mice work just fine with OTG, taking enough energy to light the LED suggests this is possible technically. I think it depends, however, on how much power does the device being charged need and if the controller in the donor device will allow this. Anyway, if this doesn't work the simple way with an ordinary OTG cable, I believe it is possible to engineer a proxy device that would make it possible.